# How to make a playlist with reactplayer?

Tags: reactjs

Here is the snippet for creating Youtube videos playlist:

```
<ReactPlayer
  url={[
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUFJJNQGwhk',
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNgP6d9HraI'
  ]}
/>
```

I want to create my own playlist (currently local files) and not from youtube url

Comment: you can't directly access local files due to some security purpose, but you can import the cloud and give the file URL.

Comment: Disappointing !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried importing the file and putting it in the url like this:

```
import myVid from './myVid.mp4'

...
<ReactPlayer
  url={myVideo}
/>
```

Try these solutions below:

1/ remove the ES6 syntax and try commonJS like this

```
...
const myVid = require("./myVid.mp4")
return (
 <ReactPlayer
   url={myVideo}
 />
)
```

2/ If you used Create React App (CRA) to create the project you can try to put the video files in the public folder and use it like this (no need importing):

```
...
return (
 <ReactPlayer
   url='myVid.mp4'
 />
)
```

Comment: Yes of course the first thing I did was to replacing the URLs with my local files, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've just added more solutions, check if it works

Comment: Thank you, but I dont have any issues with reading my local files, when I put my videos into the public folder it works perfectly and plays the video. The thing is I don't want to play a single video , I just want to create a play list with a next button from my local files

Comment: I have a solution for it but need to hardcode a little bit, if your video files is not much let's say 10 files you can rename all video files like this: myVid_1, myvid_2,...myVid_10. Then run a for loop to store all the name of your video files into an array url: [myVid_1, myVid_2,..., myVid_10]